# How to request in roads api using snap to roads?

Tags: java, android, android-async-http, google-roads-api

i would like to use the roads api to get the distance of my currentlocation and add the list of Latlng in onLocationChanged and to snap a set of coordinates (approx 100~200 points) to roads and that will return a json to get the accurate distance of driving.

-- i got a problem with path parameters the latitude and longitude is not populating in which join by this "|" but i got an error like. 
   ---This is my url

```
    protected String getSnapUrl(List<LatLng> pat_value) {
    String str_path = null;

    for (int x = 0; x < pat_value.size(); x++) {
        str_path = "path=" + pat_value.get(x).latitude + "," + pat_value.get(x).longitude + "|";
        Log.e("path", "" + pat_value.get(x).latitude + "-" + pat_value.get(x).longitude);
    }

    String str_interpolate = "interpolate=true";
    String key = "key=google key";
    String parameters = str_path + "&" + str_interpolate + "&" + key;
    String output = "snapToRoads";
    String url = output + "?" + parameters;

    return url;
}

protected void snapToRoad() {
    SnapToRoadAsyncHttpClient.get(getSnapUrl(path), null, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
            super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);
            Log.e("snapToRoad", "" + response);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse) {
            super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, throwable, errorResponse);
            Log.e("snapToRoadFail", "" + errorResponse + throwable);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
            super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, responseString, throwable);
            Log.e("snapToRoadFail", "" + responseString + throwable);
        }
    });

}
```

--Error snaptoroads error:400 message:path.

Answer (score 1):

Status code 400 is due to a invalid request.Roads API takes in at most 100 points , try decreasing your points.